# Abind list of R arrays together with dim names?

Tags: arrays, r, list

so I have a list of arrays, that is quite large. A simplified version looks like this:

```
> array_list <- list ( 'a1' = matrix(c(1,2,3,4),c(2,2)),
                       'a2' = matrix(c(5,6,7,8),c(2,2)))
```

I can use `abind` to make this a 3 dimensional array:

```
> array3 <- abind(array_list, along=0)
```

and I can give the dimensional co-ordinates names:

```
> array3 <- abind(array_list, along=0, 
                  new.names=list(c('one','two'), c('a','b'), c('u','v')))
> str(array3)
 num [1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "one" "two"
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "u" "v"
```

But I don't care about the co-ordinates. What I really want to do is give the dimensions themselves names (like a list would have). That is, something like this:

```
array3 <- abind(array_list, along=0, dim.names=c('array', 'x', 'y')
R> str(array3)
 num [1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ array: chr [1:2] "a1" "a2"
  ..$ x    : NULL
  ..$ y    : NULL
```

(notice the bits between `$ ... :`)

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Since `dimnames()` returns a list, you can use `names(dimnames(x)) <- ...` to change the names of the dimensions.

For example, change the names of the built-in dataset `Titanic`:

```
str(Titanic)
 table [1:4, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 0 0 35 0 0 0 17 0 118 154 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ Class   : chr [1:4] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "Crew"
  ..$ Sex     : chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
  ..$ Age     : chr [1:2] "Child" "Adult"
  ..$ Survived: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
```

Now change the names of the `dimnames`:

```
names(dimnames(Titanic)) <- paste0("Dim_", 1:4)
```

The result:

```
str(Titanic)
 table [1:4, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 0 0 35 0 0 0 17 0 118 154 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ Dim_1: chr [1:4] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "Crew"
  ..$ Dim_2: chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
  ..$ Dim_3: chr [1:2] "Child" "Adult"
  ..$ Dim_4: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the process of writing the code for this question (just as I was finishing) I figured out how to do it, so I thought I'd post it, for the benefit of others:

```
> array3 <- abind(array_list, along=0)
> dimnames <- c('array', 'x', 'y')
> str(array3)
 num [1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ array: NULL
  ..$ x    : NULL
  ..$ y    : NULL
```

This deletes the coordinates names, but that doesn't matter for my purposes. In case it matters to you, you can do:

```
> array3 <- abind(array_list, along=0)
> array_names <- dimnames(array3)
> names(array_names) <- c('array', 'x', 'y')
> dimnames(array3) <- array_names
> str(array3)
 num [1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ array: chr [1:2] "a1" "a2"
  ..$ x    : NULL
  ..$ y    : NULL
```